"buffer space has too many data" BufferOverflowError in fluent
This Fluentd service consumes from Kafka and stores data in OpenSearch.
The longest logs are about 32,700 bytes, while typical logs are around 10 to 15 MB.
<buffer>
      chunk_limit_size 50m
      queue_limit_length 256
      flush_mode immediate
      flush_thread_count 7
      retry_max_times 3
      retry_wait 10s
      overflow_action throw_exception
</buffer>

2024-04-29 19:02:02 +0000 [warn]: #0 failed to write data into buffer by buffer overflow action=:throw_exception
2024-04-29 19:02:02 +0000 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2024-04-29 19:02:02 +0000 [warn]: #0 emit transaction failed: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::BufferOverflowError error="buffer space has too many data" location="/usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer.rb:327:in `write'" tag="event-***"

Logs with the "event-**" tag are duplicated in OpenSearch.
Please add any other solutions or suggestion..
The retry_forever true option also results in duplicates in OpenSearch
